# Using soundcloud in an external reproductor

Tags: javascript, html, css

we are students an also a music band. we are making our website and we want to put audio streaming in a other reproductor,we want to use html/css3. we talk with our teacher and he said that we have to use the api. we want to know how to put soundclouds music in another reproductor.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you guys want to do this:
http://help.soundcloud.com/customer/portal/articles/1209780-how-to-add-soundcloud-to-your-website

more specifically: 
http://help.soundcloud.com/customer/portal/articles/1428522-what-s-new-with-the-visual-player-

All you have to do is copy the provided iframe code and whack it into your site and then you should be good to go.. I just followed the instructions on the page and it works, so good luck to you.

Comment: we know how to put soundcloud reproductor, but we want to do another thing. Example: http://www.umbro.com/es-es/  They use their owr reproductor (with HTML/CSS3). Summarizing, we want to catch souncloud song and put it using streaming.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: here you go: `<audio src="https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/46665222/stream?consumer_key=f89a7ab2e6514775a1cdb40ca5ddadd4" preload="auto" controls autoplay></audio>` Add some javascript to change src when its done and you're good to go.